# Why does TS refine the type of an array when you union it with a tuple?

Tags: typescript

```
declare const foo: number[] | [number];
const x = foo[0];
```

Why is the type of `x` `number` here, and not `undefined | number`?  It would be without the tuple union, and it doesn't make any sense to me that a union refines a type...?!?

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPCgK4C2ARiDANoC68APvNSRVbQNwBQy6WAHvAC8OPNQAMneAHpp8AJ4BLEBGDwABq0ox1AOnjwAygAskxVfEobiKUNkUoQaplqrqgA)

Comment: This seems like a bug in TS...

Comment: Hmm, waiting on https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50474#issuecomment-1229053699